# Errors running sample code - Class within an exported class - Auth0 with React Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, auth0

I am trying to run tutorial code for creating an authentication serve into my React project.

Here is the code sample that they want me to run:

```
// src/Auth/Auth.js

import auth0 from 'auth0-js';

export default class Auth {
  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain:'domain.auth0.com',
    clientID: 'clientId',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
    audience: 'https://myproject.auth0.com/userinfo',
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    scope: 'openid'
  });

  login() {
    this.auth0.authorize();
  }
}
```

When I ran it, it throws errors about the 'import' and export' keywords. 
So I changed it to this:

```
const auth0 = require("auth0-js");

class Auth {
    auth = new auth0.WebAuth({
        domain: 'mydomain.auth0.com',
        clientID: 'clientID',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
        audience: 'https://myproject.auth0.com/userinfo',
        responseType: 'token id_token',
        scope: 'openid'
  });

  login() {
    this.auth.authorize();
  }
}

module.exports = Auth;
```

But that gives me this error:

```
/Users/myname/my project/app/services/auth.js:4
    auth = new auth0.WebAuth({
         ^


SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[instance class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) are only [supported](https://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--instance-class-fields) in node >= 10 using `--harmony` flag.

You can use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) instead, that it is supported without any flag.

```
class Auth {

    get auth() {
        if(!this._auth) {
            this._auth = new auth0.WebAuth({ /* ... */ });
        }

        return this._auth;
    }

    login() {
        this.auth.authorize();
    }
}
```

Or just set it inside the `constructor`

```
class Auth {

    constructor() {

        this.auth = new Auth0.WebAuth({ /* ... */ });
    }
}
```

Or you can use [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/) to transpile your code.